# Oauth2-server-laravel custom message response

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am using [Oauth-server-laravel](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel) Authentication.

### What i have done so far:

When i post wrong `access_token` to API that i have created in laravel it gives following response,

```
{
  "error": "access_denied",
  "error_description": "The resource owner or authorization server denied the request."
}
```

I have used `oauth` as middleware in route as follow,

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Modules\User\Http\Controllers', 'middleware' => 'oauth'], function () {

    // Get User Profile Details
    Route::post('getUserProfileDetail', 'UserController@getUserProfileDetail');
});
```

### Problem:

> If credentials are wrong then oauth automatically respond with it's default message and i want to customize that response messages,

I have half succeed in that if credentials are correct then it calls function that specifies in route and in that i am appending mre response that i want to send.

```
$response = $this->authorizer->issueAccessToken();

$code = 200; //Response OK
$response['result'] = 'success';
$response['user_id'] = $user['id'];
$response['email'] = $user['email'];
$response['name'] = $user['name'];
```

But i'm unable to send it when credentials are not correct because it can't call function and send it's default response to user.

Comment: OAuth has its own format for errors, but for changing the message you would need to override the OAuthExceptionMiddleware

Comment: @ImtiazPabel if i do that then what will happen when i do composer update it will automatically update the files and my code will again overwrite...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fall this types of problem to set custom message then [this worked for me](http://www.kingpabel.com/oauth2-exception-custom-error-message/)  (a blog post I wrote about this article)]

So first create a middleware in `app/Http/Middleware.`My middleware name is `OauthExceptionMiddleware`

Then open

```
app/Http/kernel.php
```

and put this middleware instead of `oauth2` previous middleware in `$middleware` array,like this

```
protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\OauthExceptionMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

#### Oauth2 Custom Exception Error Message

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: kingpabel
 * Date: 3/23/16
 * Time: 4:40 PM
 */
namespace app\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthException;
class OauthExceptionMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try {
            $response = $next($request);
            // Was an exception thrown? If so and available catch in our middleware
            if (isset($response->exception) && $response->exception) {
                throw $response->exception;
            }
            return $response;
        } catch (OAuthException $e) {
            $data = [
//                'error' => $e->errorType,
//                'error_description' => $e->getMessage(),
                'error' => 'Custom Error',
                'error_description' => 'Custom Description',
            ];
            return \Response::json($data, $e->httpStatusCode, $e->getHttpHeaders());
        }
    }
}
```