# OAuth2 PHP change invalid_token response

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, codeigniter-4

I'm using this library : [Oauth2 PHP](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/overview/jwt-access-tokens/)

Is there a way to modify the response when token is invalid or expired from codeigniter filter?

```
class OauthFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {
        $oauth = new Oauth();
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $response = new Response();


        if(!$oauth->server->verifyResourceRequest($request)){
            $oauth->server->getResponse()->send();      
            die();
        
       }
    }

    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
    {

    }
}
```

The default response was

```
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "The access token provided is invalid"
}
```

I know that verifyResourceRequest also calls getAccessToken. When I tried it separately it returns null.

> $oauth->server->getAccessTokenData($request,$response)

Comment: How/what do you want to modify? The description/text or I didn't understand.

Comment: @b126 both the key and value and also be able to add new key value pair. In short the whole json.

Comment: I think you could use something similar to the answer suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170890/oauth2-server-laravel-custom-message-response

Comment: just dont send that response, send your own one

Comment: @delboy1978uk yes,  I can write my own json and echo it back but how would I know if the token is `invalid` , `malformed` or `expired`? `verifyResourceRequest` return a bool and `getAccessTokenData` returns null.

Comment: @delboy1978uk :  I am still not used  with SO sometimes. Wouldn’t it be flagged as duplicate if I am just adapting someone else answer?